# Jupyter-notebook and R issues: all the letters/numbers in plot labels are overlapping each other

Tags: r, plot, text, jupyter-notebook

I am using jupyter-notebook with the R-kernel to run R analysis. It was working great, but now plots are compressing labels so all the characters are overlapping.

I am using **mamba** to install the packages. I think it was fine before I installed **ancombc** and **ggforce** via **mamba**.

I have **phyloseq**, **microbiome** and **vegan** loaded. However, even with only **phyloseq** loaded, the issue persisted.

For more info I have R and the R packages installed in one **mamba** environment with jupyter-notebook installed in a separate **mamba** environment.

Additionally, if I `ggsave()` plots and display via `IRdisplay::display_png()` it is fine. I am not using this all the time as I am making this for a workshop so want to show normal plotting followed by `IRdisplay` but if noone has a good fix then I can fall back on `png()` & `ggsave()`.

Thanks for any help

Plot issue:

[image: plot with overlapping characters]

I tried `options(jupyter.plot_mimetypes = "image/png")` but this did not fix the issues.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add some code to make a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

In general, I've found that plotting behaves a bit weirdly across devices, you may want to use `ggsave` and print it to a `png` or `pdf` for consistent appearance.